# How to use bind variable in oracle report parameter form?

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have a parameter form with a value for the fiscal year and equipment ID. I want to populate the equipment ID list of values based on the fiscal year that is selected.

My query for the equipment ID list of values would be

```
SELECT EQPID,NAME FROM EQPLIST WHERE FY = :FY.
```

When I tried to add this query to the list of values of the equipment ID parameter I get

> REP-0781: Bind variables are not allowed in the Select statement.

Is there a way to dynamically generate the list of values select statement in a reports trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Cascading LoV, eh?

Which Reports version do you use? If it is 6i (client-server), I believe that your only resort is to create a parameter form using Oracle Forms, and then pass those parameters to a report.

If you're on a higher version (web-based), have a look at Metalink note 185951.1 ("How to create a parameter LOV based on another parameter value?") which includes sample code. Or, as above, create your own parameter form in Forms (that option works in any version).

Comment: I am satisfied with the answer.